# deprecated after_save solution in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, after-save

hi 
        I am create one application in rails 3 I am using paperclip in which i want to invoke one paperclip function for generate a thumbnail of image but when I invoke a after_save method it will give a error

**DEPRECATION WARNING: Base#after_save has been deprecated, please use Base.after_save :method instead. (called from  at app/models/asset.rb:23)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this: In your model, rename the method after_save to create_thumbnail and add

```
after_save :create_thumbnail
```

Comment: This is the new and correct way of doing this. Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766136/deprecation-warning-in-rails3-for-before-create-before-update-before-save-befo